# Handle error when Promise is not fulfilled

Tags: javascript, api, promise, try-catch

I am trying to pull data from cache when app is offline and print out "No internet connection" but I am keep failing to catch an error when Promise is not fulfilled i.e. when app is offline. I've tried try/catch, response.catch and other logics but none of them worked. Could someone point me to the right direction? What is wrong with my code?

```
grad = input.value ? input.value : "zagreb";


try{
  let response = await fetch(
    `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=bdbf7197ebc24abbb15104932220407&q=${grad}&aqi=yes`)
  //console.log("API-response: ", response)

  
  let data = await response.json();
  

  if (data.error) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = `<p id="nodata">No data for the requested city</p>`;
  } 
  else {
      dayTime(data);

      let rezultat = `<p id="location">${data.location.name}, ${data.location.country}, ${data.location.localtime}</p><ul id="lista">`;
          rezultat += weatherConditions(data);
          rezultat += temperatura(data);
          rezultat += cloudCover(data);
          rezultat += uvZracenje(data);
      rezultat += "</ul>";
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = rezultat;
  }
}

catch{
let cashed = ``;
data.cache = response.headers.has("cache");
console.log("kesiran data: ", data.cache)
if(data.cache){
  
cashed = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = `<p id="nointernet">No internet connection</p>`;
}

}
```

Comment: try/catch is the regular way to do so with async/await ... show how you did that as the code you posted is a frankenstein monster of async await .carch 

Comment: `response.catch`  would expect that to error, as it's no longer going to be a promise..

Comment: now, I get this error-  Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at weatherApi . Should I remove await from data and give data to catch as well

Comment: The problem is that you use `response.headers.has("cache")` in the `catch` block, but `response` is only declared in the `try` block.

Comment: *I am trying to pull data from cache when app is offline*. Consider using the [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to accomplish this.

Comment: I am having sw.js file where I defined new Headers but I though it would be too much of code to show it here whereas I only need to catch an error. Hm.. so the problem is in service workers file?!  Thank you for answers! I will try to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Attach `catch` to `fetch()` itself, from there you can set a flag or whatever that there is an error, the `response` will be `undefined` so you can check that too.

```js
async function myFunc()
{
  console.log("fetching");
  let response = await fetch(`https://whatever.com`)
    .catch(er => console.error("error", er));

  console.log("API-response: ", response)

}

myFunc();
```

```css
​.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:unset!important;overflow:auto!important}
```